# Creating custom Futures objects in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, future

I have a simple set of objects for managing a background process using the Actor model. In this case I'm concerned with only a single actor. However, it is important that the actor maintains a persistent state between receiving messages.

The objects work by appending messages to a queue in the main thread. Then the main thread can execute as it pleases. Every once in awhile it checks to see if anything new is on the results queue. When this happens it knows the actor has completed the task.

I want to know if this be implemented in a cleaner way using Futures objects. My current implementation is as follows:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import collections


class Client(object):
    """
    Object used in the main thread to communicate with background actors
    """
    def __init__(client):
        client.manager = None
        client.start()

    def __del__(client):
        if client.manager and client.manager.is_alive():
            client.get(StopIteration)

    def start(client):
        client.task_queue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
        client.result_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        client.result_history = collections.deque(maxlen=1000)
        client.manager = Manager(client.task_queue, client.result_queue)
        client.manager.start()

    def post(client, payload):
        client.task_queue.put(payload)

    def get(client, payload):
        # Exhaust any existing results
        list(client.results())
        # Post the command
        client.post(payload)
        # Wait for a response
        result = client.wait_for_result()
        return result

    def wait_for_result(client):
        wait = 0
        while True:
            for result in client.results():
                return result
            time.sleep(wait)
            wait = max(1, wait + .01)

    def results(client):
        """ Look at results put on the result_queue """
        while not client.result_queue.empty():
            item = client.result_queue.get()
            client.result_history.append(item)
            yield item


class Manager(multiprocessing.Process):
    """
    Manager manages a single actor.
    A manager sends messages an actor and appends a response when it is done.
    """
    def __init__(self, task_queue, result_queue):
        super(Manager, self).__init__()
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.result_queue = result_queue

    def run(self):
        """ main loop """
        terminate = False
        # Create Actor in separate process and send messages to it
        actor = Actor()

        while not terminate:
            message = self.task_queue.get()
            print('Sending message={} to actor'.format(message))
            try:
                if message is StopIteration:
                    content = 'shutdown'
                    terminate = True
                else:
                    content = actor.handle(message)
            except Exception as ex:
                print('Error handling message')
                status = 'error'
                content = repr(ex)
            else:
                status = 'success'
                print('Actor finished handling message={}'.format(message))

            # Send back result
            response = {
                'status': status,
                'content': content
            }
            self.task_queue.task_done()
            self.result_queue.put(response)
        print('Manager is shutting down')


class Actor(object):
    """
    An actor is given messages from its manager and performs actions in a
    single thread. Its state is private and threadsafe.
    """
    def __init__(actor):
        actor.state = {}

    def handle(actor, message):
        if not isinstance(message, dict):
            raise ValueError('Commands must be passed in a message dict')
        message = message.copy()
        action = message.pop('action', None)
        if action is None:
            raise ValueError('message must have an action item')
        if action == 'hello world':
            content = 'hello world'
            return content
        elif action == 'debug':
            return actor
        elif action == 'start':
            actor.state['a'] = 3
            return 'started'
        elif action == 'add':
            for i in range(10000000):
                actor.state['a'] += 1
            return 'added', actor.state['a']
        else:
            raise ValueError('Unknown action=%r' % (action,))


def test():
    print('Starting Test')
    client = Client()
    print('About to send messages')
    # Get sends a message and then blocks until the response is returned. 
    print(client.get({'action': 'hello world'}))
    print(client.get({'action': 'start'}))
    print(client.get({'action': 'add'}))
    print('Test completed')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

I would like to modify this code to use Future objects. Whenever the client is about to send a message, is it possible to create a Future object, then send that over the multiprocessing queue? Then the manager could execute the actors function and then modify the state of the Future object instead of appending a result to the result_queue.

This seems like it would offer a cleaner way to associate results with messages sent to the actor. It would also remove the need for the get and results methods I have in the first example.

Intuitively, I want it to look something like this:

```
from concurrent import futures
import multiprocessing


class Client(object):
    """
    Object used in the main thread to communicate with background actors
    """
    def __init__(client):
        client.manager = None
        client.start()

    def __del__(client):
        if client.manager and client.manager.is_alive():
            f = client.post(StopIteration)

    def start(client):
        client.task_queue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
        client.manager = Manager(client.task_queue)
        client.manager.start()

    def post(client, payload):
        f = futures.Future()
        client.task_queue.put((f, payload))
        return f


class Manager(multiprocessing.Process):
    """
    Manager manages a single actor.
    """
    def __init__(self, task_queue):
        super(Manager, self).__init__()
        self.task_queue = task_queue

    def run(self):
        """ main loop """
        terminate = False
        # Create Actor in separate process and send messages to it
        actor = Actor()

        while not terminate:
            f, message = self.task_queue.get()
            f.set_running_or_notify_cancel()
            print('Sending message={} to actor'.format(message))
            try:
                if message is StopIteration:
                    content = 'shutdown'
                    terminate = True
                else:
                    content = actor.handle(message)
            except Exception as ex:
                print('Error handling message')
                status = 'error'
                content = repr(ex)
            else:
                status = 'success'
                print('Actor finished handling message={}'.format(message))

            # Send back result
            response = {
                'status': status,
                'content': content
            }
            self.task_queue.task_done()
            f.set_result(response)
        print('Manager is shutting down')


class Actor(object):
    """
    An actor is given messages from its manager and performs actions in a
    single thread. Its state is private and threadsafe.
    """
    def __init__(actor):
        actor.state = {}

    def handle(actor, message):
        if not isinstance(message, dict):
            raise ValueError('Commands must be passed in a message dict')
        message = message.copy()
        action = message.pop('action', None)
        if action is None:
            raise ValueError('message must have an action item')
        if action == 'hello world':
            content = 'hello world'
            return content
        elif action == 'debug':
            return actor
        elif action == 'start':
            actor.state['a'] = 3
            return 'started'
        elif action == 'add':
            for i in range(10000000):
                actor.state['a'] += 1
            return 'added', actor.state['a']
        else:
            raise ValueError('Unknown action=%r' % (action,))


def test():
    print('Starting Test')
    client = Client()
    print('About to send messages')
    f1 = client.post({'action': 'hello world'})
    print(f1.result())
    f2 = client.post({'action': 'start'})
    print(f2.result())
    f3 = client.post({'action': 'add'})
    print(f3.result())
    print('Test completed')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

However, this obviously doesn't execute correctly. I believe I need some sort of process pool manager to create the futures for me (because I'm calling methods that are documented saying that only the pool manager should call them). But I'm not quite sure how to go about doing that. I've used futures before to map singleton worker functions, but I've never managed an external process with state before.

Can someone help me out with this? Perhaps there is an even easier way to go about implementing this with Futures?

Answer (score 0):

So, I went ahead and just made a library to do this:

https://github.com/Erotemic/futures_actors